# How to auto scale apache zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Anyone using Auto Scale to scale you Zookeeper cluster? If the zookeeper scale, how clients know it has been scale up or down? Specially like Kafka where the zookeeper list is being added into config file, what happen zookeeper scaled how kafka now it has been scale etc?

Comment: Are you referring to AWS - Auto Scale?  And regarding Zookeeper, how many nodes are you expecting to have in your cluster?

Comment: Yes AWS auto scale, We probably plan to have 3 nodes for the initial start and then auto scale when it grow or if needed. Just curious how clients get notified with the change? I noticed kafka is having the zookeeper list in the config file, then how it know if new nodes being added etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: ZooKeeper clients do not need to essentially know/track if there are new nodes added to the ZooKeeper cluster. They just need at least one ZK node available (healthy) for them.

Longer answer (with Kafka as example client of ZK):

1. If you're only adding new nodes to the ZooKeeper cluster, it's not essential for Kafka brokers to know about this, because the `zookeeper.connect` configuration still contains healthy ZK nodes.
2. If however, you're replacing/removing some of the ZooKeeper nodes, and these are the only nodes present in the `zookeeper.connect` configuration, then a rolling restart of the Kafka nodes will be required, after updating the `zookeeper.connect` configuration.

For #1 above, best to add the new ZK nodes to the Kafka configuration at the next opportunity of Kafka cluster restart.

Same is applicable for other technologies also that depend on ZK (e.g. Apache Storm).